# All Values of TextView is not Visible in Android Emulator

Tags: android, textview

I am very novice to Android and trying to show certain values into the Textview.I am testing my app in emulator.Here is my code in java..

```
status.setText(("PNR:       "+pnr+"\n"+
    "Train No:              "+trainNum+"\n"+
    "Train Name:            "+trainName+"\n"+
    "Date Of Journey:       "+date+"\n"+
    "From Station   :       "+fromname+"\n"+
    "To Station     :       "+toname+"\n"+
    "ReservationUpTo:       "+uptoname+"\n"+
    "Boarding Point :       "+boardtoname+"\n"+
    "Class          :       "+classvalue+"\n"+
    "Chart Status   :       "+chartstatus+"\n"+
    "No Of Passenger:       "+noofpass+"\n"+
    "Booking Status :       "+booking_status+"\n"+
    "Current Status :       "+current_status+"\n"
));
```

But while seeing it into Emulator i am not able to see values after `"ReservationUpTo:`So my question is will this be in Phone also or all values will be seen by scrolling the screen.

I wont have real android phone to test this app.sorry.

Please help me..

Here is my `TextView`..

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="6"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Comment: u just put textview height="match_parent" hope it ll work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="6"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#0f0f0f" />
```

Answer (score 1):

include your testview inside a [scrollview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) and you should be able to view all your text by scroll even in an emulator

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/textView2"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_column="0"
 android:layout_columnSpan="6"
 android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
 android:layout_row="6"
 android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<ScrollView/>
```

Comment: Sir i have updated my textview xml ..Please see and help me how to include scroll in it..

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your xml

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:maxLines="4" // or an higher value
android:lines="4"    //also here
```